# I want to switch languages in my dialogflow chatbot

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have made a chatbot with intents in English and Hindi language with English as default and integrated it with slack but I want to change the language to Hindi in the chatbot when I reply in hindi or maybe pass a intent which switches the language.